# Rails: Create action not saving has_many through associations - "rollback transaction"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, has-many-through

Be easy on me, I'm just starting to learn Rails and this is my first question on here!

The project I'm using to learn is a volleyball scoreboard, so right now I'm trying to build a form that will submit the score of a 2v2 game. I have ***users*** and ***games*** which are associated by a has_many through relationship to a join table of ***participants*** which also includes a 'result' attribute ('W' or 'L').

My problem is that when I submit it fails, and no ***participants*** are created. If I removed the associations from the form, submission will work with just game parameters.

Hopefully, I've included all the relevant information below. Also, if there is a better way to do all this, I'd love to hear it!

MODELS

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :venue
  has_many :participants
  has_many :users, through: :participants

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :participants,
    reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :participants
  has_many :games, through: :participants
end

class Participant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :user
end
```

SCHEMA

```
create_table "games", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date     "game_date"
    t.integer  "winning_score"
    t.integer  "losing_score"
    t.text     "notes"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
    t.integer  "venue_id"
    t.index ["venue_id"], name: "index_games_on_venue_id"
end

create_table "participants", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "game_id"
  t.string   "result"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["game_id"], name: "index_participants_on_game_id"
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_participants_on_user_id"
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "email"
  t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  t.string   "password_digest"
  t.string   "remember_digest"
  t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
end

create_table "venues", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

CONTROLLER

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @users = User.all
    @game = Game.new
    @game.participants.build
  end

  def create
    @game = Game.new(game_params)

    if @game.save
      redirect_to 'show'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def game_params
      params.require(:game).permit(:game_date, :winning_score,
                                   :losing_score, :notes, :venue_id,
                                   participants_attributes: [:user_id, :result, 
                                   :_destroy])
    end

end
```

FORM

```
<%= simple_form_for @game do |f| %>
  <div id="winners">
    <b>Winners</b>
    <% for i in 0..1 %>
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :participants do |p| %>
        <%= p.association :user, :collection => @users, label: false %>
        <%= p.input :result, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => 'W' }%>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <%= f.input :winning_score, :collection => 15..30 %>

  <div id="losers">
    <b>Losers</b>
    <% for i in 2..3 %>
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :participants do |p| %>
        <%= p.association :user, :collection => @users, label: false %>
        <%= p.input :result, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => 'L' }%>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <%= f.input :losing_score, :collection => 0..30 %>

  <%= f.input :notes %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit!", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
```

RESPONSE

```
Processing by GamesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"p8081+wU7EqYV7PIIAOGP3N+Md4CJusFpL9qTm3CeC54fP7pTPEwtfYS5v5x+ErBWxGiB0oj1pklYGXwl/cRBw==", "game"=>{"participants_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"user_id"=>"3", "result"=>"W"}, "1"=>{"user_id"=>"2", "result"=>"W"}, "2"=>{"user_id"=>"1", "result"=>"W"}, "3"=>{"user_id"=>"6", "result"=>"W"}}, "winning_score"=>"18", "losing_score"=>"4", "notes"=>"13241234"}, "commit"=>"Submit!"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendering games/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered games/new.html.erb within layouts/application (69.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 199ms (Views: 144.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

Comment: change `has_many :participants` to `has_many :participants, inverse_of: :game`

Comment: thanks @Kkulikovskis that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kkulikovskis comment worked for me. I changed:

```
has_many :participants
```

to

```
has_many :participants, inverse_of: :game
```

in the game model